# Does plaid link include non depository accounts

Tags: hyperlink, plaid

Does the plaid link product (https://plaid.com/docs/link/) include non depository accounts? From what I've seen, it only seems to include depository accounts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does.

For a full matrix of supported products by account type, see the [API Reference](https://plaid.com/docs/api/accounts/#account-type--product-support-matrix).

Note that Link isn't in that table because it's the frontend used for every Plaid product, so anything that is supported by *any* Plaid product is necessarily supported by Link.